# How to change id attribute with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How can I change the `id` attribute value from `/` to something like: `-`? Here is what is have:

```
<div id="Over/Under">
```

I tried to do this with JQuery:

```
$('[id^="Over/Under"]').each(function(){
  this.id = this.id.replace('Over/Under', 'over-under');  // Replace Id
});
```

However it's not working. Note that I don't have direct access to the `id` value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to change the `id` attribute of any tag with a forward-slash (`/`) to a hyphen (`-`).

You can easily achieve that using a `id*=` selector:

```js
$('[id*="/"]').each(function(){
    console.log('ID before: ' + $(this).attr('id'));
    $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id').replace('/', '-'));
    console.log('ID after: ' + $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="user/name">
```

This will find all elements with an `id` containing a forward-slash, and replace the `id` with a hyphenated one instead.

Console output:

```
ID before: user/name
ID after: user-name
```